# sqlite3 "ON DELETE RESTRICT" via SQLAlchemy not being honored, but works fine in sqlite3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I've got an issue with sqlite3 and SQLAlchemy, where my foreign key is created with a ForeignKey with ondelete="RESTRICT", and every session executes "PRAGMA foreign_keys = on", but SQLAlchemy still allows me to orphan a child.  Attempting to delete the same row in sqlite3 itself properly throws a foreign key error.

Here's my SQLAlchemy models:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    username = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    account_type = Column(String, ForeignKey("account_types.name", ondelete="RESTRICT"), nullable=False)

class AccountType(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'account_types'

    name = Column(String, nullable=False, unique=True, primary_key=True)
    description = Column(String)
```

Now, I open a connection to the database and do the following:

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite3:///mydatabase")
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()
session.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = on")

# This gives me the expected result:
# I can't add a user which references an account type I haven't 
# created yet
new_user = User(username="abc123",
                account_type="admin") # "admin" doesn't exist yet
session.add(new_user)
with pytest.raises(sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError):
    session.commit()
session.rollback()

new_account_type = AccountType(name="admin",
                               description="blah blah blah")
session.add(new_account_type)
session.commit()

# Now add our new user (Horray, this now works!)
session.add(new_user)
session.commit()

# Now let's try to delete the account type
# This should raise an integrity error, but it doesn't!
# SELECT * FROM account_types and SELECT * FROM users
# show that the user still exists, but the account type doesn't
session.query(AccountType).filter_by(name="admin").delete()
session.commit()
```

Now, take SQLAlchemy out of the equation, clear the tables, and manually INSERT/DELETE this data, and sqlite3 is honoring the "ON DELETE RESTRICT":

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = on;

sqlite> DELETE FROM users;
sqlite> DELETE FROM account_types;

sqlite> .schema users       
CREATE TABLE users (
        username VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        account_type VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (username), 
        UNIQUE (username), 
        FOREIGN KEY(account_type) REFERENCES account_types (name) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

sqlite> .schema account_types
CREATE TABLE account_types (
        name VARCHAR NOT NULL, 
        description VARCHAR, 
        PRIMARY KEY (name), 
        UNIQUE (name)
);

sqlite> INSERT INTO account_types VALUES ("admin", "blah blah blah");
sqlite> INSERT INTO users VALUES ("abc123", "admin");

sqlite> DELETE FROM account_types WHERE name = "admin";
Error: FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

=====================================================

**Why won't SQLAlchemy (1.0.12) respect the "ON DELETE RESTRICT" constraint in sqlite3?**

If it matters, the tables (and the constraints) were all generated through SQLAlchemy:

```
engine = create_engine("sqlite3:///mydatabase")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrestled with this for about two hours before posting, then about an hour after posting, I figured it out.  Here's the answer for any other lonely SQLAlchemy newbie who reaches this page now or years down the road.  "session.rollback()" was "undoing" my previous execution of "PRAGMA foreign_keys = on".

I had pulled that method of setting up the session from some previous internal source code, so I assumed it was okay.  The manual lays out exactly how this should be handled at http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/dialects/sqlite.html#foreign-key-support

In short, I added:

```
from sqlalchemy import event
from sqlalchemy.engine import Engine

@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")
    cursor.close()
```

to my module which contains all my models, and it just "works".  This method doesn't need to be invoked in any way.  Now my foreign key constraints are *always* being respected, even post-rollback.